# How to get selected items of a checkboxlist using a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist, foreach-loop-container

I have a checkboxlist which is populated from the database. Number of items in the list can be differed. I want to get all the selected values using a foreach loop and store it in the database. How can i do it?

Comment: any implementation? you have tried?

Comment: A foreach will work to get the selected value of a number of check boxes. What have you tried? Where is your code? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can use a foreach loop and test every checkbox list element if it is checked like this:

```
foreach (ListItem item in youListName.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected){
                //do something with your item
            }
        }
```